# Reference appened HTML code via id with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem concerning the use of .append("..."). I am coding a simple To-Do List and want to delete a list element when I click on the appended "REMOVE" button by reference to the buttons class.

I think it is not working because .append() isn't changing the html code of the website. At least I can't spot a difference after clicking the "ADD ITEM" button.

Do you have any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

```
var inputText;
var itemList = [];


$("#addButton").click(function(){
    inputText = $("#textInput").val();
    itemList.push(inputText);
    $("#textInput").val("");
    showItems();
});

//not working
$(".deleteButton").click(function(e){
    console.log("test");
    var className = e.attr("id");
    console.log("ID:" + className);
});

function showItems(){
    $("#list").html('');
    for(var i=0; i<=itemList.length-1; i++){
        $("#list").append('<div class="listelement"><p type="text" class="listItem" id="listItem '+ i +'">'+ itemList[i] +'</p> <button type="button" class="deleteButton" id="'+ i +'">REMOVE</button><div>');
    }
}
```

```
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="headline">
                <h1 id="headline">TO DO LIST</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="userInput">
                <input type="text" id="textInput">
                <button type="button" id="addButton">ADD ITEM</button>
            </div>
            <div class="list" id="list">
                <div class="listelement" id="listelement">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to remove that specific div where you are clicking you can use following code. You dont need to match id here.

```
$(document).on("click",".deleteButton",function(e){
    let parent = $(this).closest(".listelement");
    parent.remove();
});
```

But according to your code after delete if you add something, all the data of the array will show.Because you are not deleting data from array. I think you need to delete that data from the array too.

```
$(document).on("click",".deleteButton",function(e){
    let parent = $(this).closest(".listelement");
    let id = $(this).attr("id");
    console.log(id);
    itemList.splice(id, 1);
     parent.remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use event delegation.

```
$(document).on("click",".deleteButton",function(e) {
  $(this).closest(".listelement").remove()
});
```

`$(".deleteButton").click(function(e){` will only work on those elements that exist on the page, but not on newly added elements.

```js
var inputText;
var itemList = [];


$("#addButton").click(function() {
  inputText = $("#textInput").val();
  itemList.push(inputText);
  $("#textInput").val("");
  showItems();
});

//not working
$(document).on("click",".deleteButton",function(e) {
  $(this).closest(".listelement").remove()
});

function showItems() {
  $("#list").html('');
  for (var i = 0; i <= itemList.length - 1; i++) {
    $("#list").append('<div class="listelement"><p type="text" class="listItem" id="listItem ' + i + '">' + itemList[i] + '</p> <button type="button" class="deleteButton" id="' + i + '">REMOVE</button><div>');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="headline">
    <h1 id="headline">TO DO LIST</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="userInput">
    <input type="text" id="textInput">
    <button type="button" id="addButton">ADD ITEM</button>
  </div>
  <div class="list" id="list">
    <div class="listelement" id="listelement">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the element appended doesn't have an event listener attached to it, when you're calling `$(...).click` it will attach an event listener only to the currently existing elements. Since you're calling it when the document loads and there are no elements with the class `deleteButton` at that time it won't do anything.

You can solve this by moving the deletion code to it's own function and attaching a click event listener for each new element you create.

In order to do so efficiently, you'll need to get the element you're creating, you can do this like so:

```
$(HTML Code).appendTo('#list').click(...);
```

This will create an element from the html you pass it, append it to the element with the id `list` and attach a click event listener to it, so in the end this will the result:

```js
var inputText;
var itemList = [];


$("#addButton").click(function() {
  inputText = $("#textInput").val();
  itemList.push(inputText);
  $("#textInput").val("");
  showItems();
});

function deleteItem(e) {
  console.log(e.target.id);
}

function showItems() {
  $("#list").html('');
  for (var i = 0; i <= itemList.length - 1; i++) {
    var html = '<div class="listelement"><p type="text" class="listItem" id="listItem ' + i + '">' + itemList[i] + '</p> <button type="button" class="deleteButton" id="' + i + '">REMOVE</button><div>';
    $(html).appendTo('#list').click(deleteItem);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="headline">
    <h1 id="headline">TO DO LIST</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="userInput">
    <input type="text" id="textInput">
    <button type="button" id="addButton">ADD ITEM</button>
  </div>
  <div class="list" id="list">
    <div class="listelement" id="listelement">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to do something with the elements that are dynamically added to DOM using the jQuery click() method it will not work, because it bind the click event only to the elements that exist at the time of binding
you can use

```
$(document).on("click", "button.deleteButton" , function() {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/82d0e5at/3/